# Finding value of $ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int^{1}_{0}x^{2019}\cdot \sin (nx)\,dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

> Finding value of $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int^{1}_{0}x^{2019}\cdot \sin (nx)\,dx$$

what i try

$$I = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int^{1}_{0}x^{2019}\cdot \sin (nx)dx$$

Integration by parts

$$I=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\bigg[-x^{2019}\cdot \frac{\cos (nx)}{n}\Bigg|^{1}_{0}+2019\int^{1}_{0}x^{2018}\frac{\cos(nx)}{n}dx\bigg]$$

$$I=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{2019}{n}\int^{1}_{0}x^{2018}\cos(nx)dx$$

How do i solve it please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are nearly done. We have
$$
\vert \frac{2019}{n}\int^{1}_{0}x^{2018}\cos(nx) dx \vert \le \frac{2019}{n}\int^{1}_{0}x^{2018}dx = \frac{2019}{2019n}= \frac{1}{n}
$$
Can you finish?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply apply [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma).

Comment: Isn't it too much for this simple problem?